# PHP - Google Line Chart “Table has no columns” - How to get rows and cols in JSON

Tags: php, charts

I'm having problems with parsing my JSON data into a Google Line Chart.
I get the error “Table has no columns”

So I took a look at Google JSON and theirs look like this:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

I have written this JSON function in PHP so far

```
function generateJSON($user_id){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `csvupload` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
}
```

And the output goes like this:

```
[{"user_id":"1","item1":"Jim","item2":"Smith","item3":"jim@tester.com"},{"user_id":"1","item1":"Joe","item2":"Tester","item3":"joe@tester.com"}]
```

Does someone know how I can the "rows" and "cols" have google has it? Cause now I only get the error "Table has no columns". Any help is appreciated! :)